# strapi how to limit content added by user

Tags: strapi

I don't want users to add more than 3 content.

**Example**: I want to have **demo users** which will be able to add just 3 items in to **things to do.**
Payed customers will add with out any limit.

**Is there a way to stop users adding new content after 3 content?**
I need Roles with limited create content permissions.

**Note**: we'll be using api endpoint to add content

I couldn't find a way.

Comment: Hello, are you using the admin panel or the generate API endpoint to add your data?

Comment: @JimLAURIE Thank you for front-end idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: was to **limit users from updating content** in **front-end**.

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/content-api/api-endpoints.html#create-an-entry

Thanks to @jim-laurie